# Using count returns 1 always in android sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, count

I am trying to retrieve the total count of rows from `Sqlite` Database. I have used the following code, but the problem is that the count is always 1 even though there are more than one row satisfying the conditions. Can anyone guide me where I am going wrong.

```
public int get_report_entry_area_count(String jobId, String area,
        String sensor) {

    String countQuery = "select count(*) from report1 where JobId='"
        + jobId + "' and sensor='" + sensor + "'" + " and Area='"
            + area + "'";

    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();

    Cursor c = database.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    int total = c.getCount();
    c.close();
    return total;

}
```

Comment: Probably Strings in condition causing issue so first try it with only `JobId` where condition. let us know still getting count 1?

Comment: I tried String countQuery="select count(*) from report1" but still count is 1

Comment: change this query String countQuery = "select * from report1 where JobId='"+ jobId + "' and sensor='" + sensor + "'" + " and Area='"+ area + "'";

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Using count returns 1 always in android sqlite

Because `c.getCount()` return number of items in provided `Cursor` instead of `count` query result.

Get count result as from `Cursor` :

```
c.moveToFirst();
int total = c.getInt(0);
```